# php skipping first row of result from mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Using while loop, it is skipping the first row and using do while loop, it is showing the last row. The code is as follows :

```
$query = "select * from sear where wrrnt_no like '%".$text."%'";
$result = $connection->query($query);
echo "<table>";
while(($row = $result->fetch_assoc())!==null) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td width=".'10'.">";
  $warrent = $row[0];
  echo $warrent;
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td width=".'10'.">";
  $warrent_date = $row[1];
  echo $warrent_date;
  echo "</td>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Thank you for your replies in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can have an index counter in your for each loop, and ignore the first reason. Not the best but will work.

Comment: Dump your query results and check results, maybe it's sth wrong with your query.

Comment: Your question is unclear: is the fact that it skips rows (every second) the issue you ask about or do you actually want to skip exactly the first row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you fetch the row twice.
Once with `$result->fetch_assoc` and another time with `mysqli_fetch_row`.

So you need to remove this line: `$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);` because the row is already fetched.

I think it's not the last or first line that is missing, but half of the rows from table. In one case starting with first and in another case starting with second.

**UPDATED**

If you want to have numeric index you will need to use `fetch_row`. So change the code to:

```
$query = "select * from sear where wrrnt_no like '%".$text."%'";
$result = $connection->query($query);
echo "<table>";
while(($row = $result->fetch_row())!==null)
{

  $warrent = $row[0];
  //...the rest of echo here
}
```

But I recommend to use `fetch_assoc` and after that to use the name of the column like this: `$warrent = $row['wrrnt_no'];` (if that is what you need)

Comment: The question is not yet clear in my eyes...

Comment: @arkascha For me it's clear. If he try like in the example with `for` he will get not get the first result from table. If he will change to `do-while` he will not get the last results from table printed. And the problem is that he is fetching twice from db.

Comment: It certainly is wrong to fetch twice, sure. But to me the actual goal is unclear, so what the OP actually wants to achieve.

Comment: @Daniel If I remove the line $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

Comment: @Daniel, if I remove the line $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); then its showing error as Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\search.php on line 87

Comment: @arkascha, result should be the complete table from database and should not skip any value.

Comment: Ok, then stop fetching two rows with each loop iteration. And maybe you now see why a _precise_ question is a very important thing ;-)

Comment: @AtulPatil I updated my answer with your second problem. You need to use `fetch_row` if you want to have numeric indexes. But I recommend to use `fetch_assoc` and after that use name of the column (as string)

Comment: while(($row = $result->fetch_row())!==null)

Comment: @DanielDudas while(($row = $result->fetch_row())!==null)  this updation worked fine..  thank you so much..